# ggplot labels with "K" for thousands or "M" for millions (maintaining 'comma' y-axis labeling)

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- mpg %>% head() %>% mutate(hwy = hwy * 10000)
ggplot(df, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::comma) +
  geom_text(aes(label = hwy), hjust = -0.25)
```

I want the labels on this plot to use "K" for thousands (eg `260K` instead of `260000`). BUT - I want to maintain the y-axis as is, with commas (eg `260,000`). How can I achieve this?

[image: geom text desired thousand but have commas]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `scales::label_number_si()`:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(label = comma) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label_number_si()(hwy)), hjust = -0.25)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To keep this up to date, from version 1.2 of {scales}, the final line should use `cut_short_scale()` as `label_number_si()` is deprecated

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

df <- mpg %>% head() %>% mutate(hwy = hwy * 10000)
ggplot(df, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(label = scales::comma) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label_number(scale_cut = cut_short_scale())(hwy)), 
            hjust = -0.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a custom column called `myLabel` to your dataframe which holds your desired labels. In the package `scales` you can find a function that does the converting part for you:

```
df <- mpg %>% head() %>% mutate(hwy = hwy * 10000)
df$myLabels <- scales::label_number_si()(df$hwy)
```

Now, use the new column `myLabels` as the aesthetic for creating the labels

```
    ggplot(df, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_continuous(label = scales::comma) +
    geom_text(aes(label = myLabels), hjust = -0.25)
```